# Problem with form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to implement a form for let the user change their password.

Here the code:

**forms.py**

```
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), required = True)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), required = True)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The two password fields didn't match.")
        return password2

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        self.user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        print "Pass setted."
        self.user.save()
```

**views.py**

```
def change_password(request):
    form = ChangePasswordForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST, instance = request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1'];
            password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2'];
            print password1 + " == " + password2
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Password updated!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')

    return render(request, 'change_password.html', {'form': form})
```

It doesn't work because user is not defined. The problem is how to pass **user** to the form. Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make it a parameter to the `save` method.

```
def save(self, user):
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    user.save()

...


form.save(request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

user colud be  taken from `request.user` in general

Comment: Yes but my question was how can I pass that to the form.