# Cannot Authenticate Registered User

Tags: python, django, registration

I've expanded the default django user model with the AbstractUser mixin.  When I register the user I recieve the `User created successfully` message.  But when I try to log in, the user does not authenticate.  It returns `Wrong username/password`.  The `user_login` method worked with the default user model before I started using the abstractuser class.  I know that the data inserts in to the database because I cannot register the same user more than once.  I wonder if its not authenticating because the user registration method is not salting the password?  Any help is appreciated.

tl;dr:  Cannot authenticate a user that was registered with the `user_register` method.  Why?

settings.py

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"`

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail-user', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

views.py

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                return HttpResponse('User created succcessfully.')
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()

        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        context['form'] = form

        return render_to_response('/', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Not active")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Wrong username/password")
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

template.html

```
<form action="/users/create" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>Username</h4>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="admin">
    <h4>Email</h4>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="admin@mail.com">
    <h4>Password</h4>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <div class="btn-list">
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Sorry for the wall of code.  I wanted to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: You would have to set the password using `user.set_password()` method for the `authentication` to work. You would do that by overriding the `save` method

Comment: @karthikr So something like `form.user.set_password(request.POST['password']).save()`?  Sorry I'm new to user registration in django.

Comment: No - in the `class UserRegisterForm` Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956619/problem-with-form-in-django